# Get the list of recently installed packages - Yarn / NPM

Tags: npm, node-modules, yarnpkg

Is there any way to get a list of recently installed packages in Yarn or NPM? For instance, I recently installed Package A and a couple other dependencies B, C and D. 
Now I don't want package A and I would like to remove A, B, C and D from my node modules directory and I forgot the names of C and D.

Is there any way I can view a list of recently installed packages in a chronological order?

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty well: `npm list -g --depth=0`

Comment: This command lists all the packages installed so far. I would like to know whether there is a way to list the packages in the order I installed them. Thanks anyways!

Comment: npm-ls may do the job for you